# How to get "," separated output using awk command in linux

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to print the output of awk command with "," delimited.
Trying to get the same output using cut.

```
cat File1
dot|is-big|a
dot|is-round|a
dot|is-gray|b
cat|is-big|a
hot|in-summer|a
dot|is-big|a
dot|is-round|b
dot|is-gray|a
cat|is-big|a
hot|in-summer|a
```

Command tried :

```
$awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","} {print $1,$3}'  file1.csv | sort |  uniq -c
```

Output Got:

```
  2 cat,a
  4 dot,a
  2 dot,b
  2 hot,a
```

Desired Output:

```
  2,cat,a
  4,dot,a
  2,dot,b
  2,hot,a
```

Couple of other commands tried :

```
$cat file1.csv |cut --output-delimiter="|"  -d'|' -f1,3 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: the **problem** is that the space gets put in by `uniq -c`, which you execute after the awk

Comment: Expanding on that, the problem is unrelated to awk. Sadly `uniq -c` doesn't allow specifying the delimeter, so use some regex and substitute the first space after the first number in line by a comma with ex. `sed`.

Comment: You could track the count in awk and not have to call uniq at all.  eg `awk '{a[$1","$3]++}END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}' FS=\| OFS=, file1.csv | sort -t, -k2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter to `,` *after* running `uniq -c`, since it's adding the first column.

```
awk -F'|' '{print $1, $3}' file1.csv | sort | uniq -c | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1;print}'
```

But you don't need to use `sort | uniq -c` if you're using `awk`, it can do the counting itself.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=","} {a[$1 OFS $3]++} END{for(k in a) print a[k], k}' file1.csv
```

Comment: Does posix guarantee that `for (k in a)` iterates in an appropriately sorted ordering? Isn't sorting a gawk extension?

Comment: This works as expected `{awk -F'|' '{print $1, $3}' file1.csv | sort | uniq -c | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1;print}'} `. But is there a way that I can optimize the output like 
`(count:"2",Subject:"cat",Category:"a"),(count:"4",Subject:"dot",Category:"a"),(count:"2",Subject:"cat",Category:"b"),(count:"2",Subject:"hot",Category:"a") ` All in one single line??

Comment: That looks *almost* like JSON, why not use a utility like `jq` to make real JSON?

Comment: You can use my second method and change the `END` block to print it in the format that you want.